# Firebase JSON file for multiple apps

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, firebase-analytics

We have a 25 apps (25 modules) which uses a common module where the code for AdMob is done.

Since we dont need deep analytics for each and every app, we are using same AdMob application id for all the apps and it was working perfect.
Now the Firebase is there, its JSON file have the package name of the app.

How do we use same JSON file for all the apps?

Answer (score 2):

You need to compulsory create separate JSON file for different.

Comment: What about that module that i use only for adintegration with other 25 apps, which json file will i copy there? all the json files? it says name doesnt match

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use that json file for all the module as it contains project number and api key so you need to download json file for your all module or app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create separate `google-services.json` file for all modules.

### You can **add multiple app in one project**.

Here are some step to do so.

> 1. Go to your firebase console
> 2. Select your previous project and Add another app
> 3. Register another applicationId (Register all of your applicationID one by one)
> 4. Then Download new `google-services.json`
> 5. And place new `google-services.json` in your project

Thats it